# Change city when parsing website with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

As I understood `Scrapy` works asynchronously and requests are unordered.
Now, I can parse a list of items on some website's page and go to details to parse additional information.
The problem is that after doing all of that work, I need to parse same data for another city.
City changes by making request like `http://www.example.com/city/set/1`.

My spider looks like this :

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for category in CATEGORIES:
            if 'subcategories' in category:
                subcategories = category['subcategories']
                for subcategory in subcategories:
                    url = subcategory['url']
                    yield scrapy.Request(
                        url = url, 
                        callback = self.parse, 
                        meta = {
                            'category': category,
                            'subcategory': subcategory
                        }
                    )

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

What is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply chain requests:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = dict()
    # fill up item with data
    city_url = '' #make city url
    yield Request(city_url,
                  meta={'item': item},  # carry item to next callback in meta
                  callback=self.parse_city)

def parse_city(self, response):
    # get item from meta
    item = response.meta['item']
    # add more stuff to your item
    item['some_city_data'] = ''
    yield item
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem correctly. For each city there are different items, therefore I don't need to carry item. For example, calling `http://www.example.com/city/set/1` saves city id for session. Then I need parse all items for that city, after finishing I need to set city id for another value and parse items again.

Comment: @Chika Oh, I see. If the session is set in the cookie then you can simply create multiple sessions, add every city url to `start_urls` and add `dont_filter=True` to your request like:  `Requests(dont_filter=True)` to avoid filtering.